# Netbeans not working with Xdebug

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I have installed `XAMPP` and placed the `xdebug` file as recommended by http://xdebug.org/wizard.php based on result of my `phpInfo();`

I also have `Netbeans 8.02` installed, I created new `PHP` project in `Netbeans` & applied break points but as I debug the file by using `Ctrl+Shift+F5` complete web page is loaded and control does not stop at the `break point` where it should. What did I miss? Do I need to configure `Netbeans` to work with `xdebug`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved, I had to replace

```
;xdebug.remote_enable = 0
```

with

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
```